# ObservableBoolean calling set(true) immediately followed by set(false) results in only getting the false callback

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have an ObservableBoolean as follows:

```
public final ObservableBoolean searching = new ObservableBoolean(false);
```

I then have a method to perform an HTTP request:

```
public void search() {
    searching.set(true);

    // Perform HTTP request, then on Result:
    searching.set(false);
}
```

I have a view bound to "searching" which triggers a custom BindingAdapter method, passing in the value of searching.

The above works well when there is a pause between searching.set(true) and searching.set(false), as is the case when an asyncronous HTTP request is made. I get two callbacks to my BindingAdapter method as expected, one true, and one false.

Problem arises when I cache the search results and the HTTP request is no longer required. In this case, there is no pause between searching.set(true) and searching.set(false), like so:

```
public void search() {
    searching.set(true);
    searching.set(false);
}
```

With this code I only get the false callback to my BindingAdapter method. What happened to the true callback? Why is it getting dropped? Is there a way to prevent it from getting dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as designed. Android data binding sets all values in a posted message, so only one last set call is made. This is intended to be a performance improvement among other things.

If you want to ensure the call is made inline, you can force evaluation of bindings:

```
public void search() {
    searching.set(true);
    binding.executePendingBindings();
    searching.set(false);
}
```

This assumes that `search()` is executed on the UI thread. If it isn't, you'll have to post it because `executePendingBindings()` must be run on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am running this code from within a ViewModel so I don't have a reference to the binding. I'm instead using LiveData to communicate a search event back to the fragment and the fragment will respond accordingly.